# Is this an appropriate replacement for our current bathroom extractor fan?

Tags: exhaust-fan

Our existing fan is old, inefficient and extremely loud. I believe it is an old P Series centrifugal extractor made by Greenwood Airvac, although I am unable to be certain as the model and serial numbers have both faded to the point that they are unreadable. A picture of the unit without its cover is included below:

[image]

I have found a model I would like to replace it with - [an ST100B Silent Tornado Hi-Power Bathroom Fan](https://www.extractorfanworld.co.uk/st100b-silent-tornado-hi-power-bathroom-fan-3431-p.asp), but I don't understand enough to know whether it will be possible to easily replace one with the other. For example, do they require different diameter venting holes?

I intend to employ an electrician to do the actual work, so I do not require any detail beyond whether the model I have chosen is a suitable and easy to install replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without seeing the current installation. Rather than answering the question directly, I'll give you some tools to make the assessment yourself.

There are a few basic considerations when seeking a replacement fan, aside from feature preferences...

- Housing size
- Housing mount type and location
- Grille size (for coverage of the existing ceiling opening)
- Duct size
- Duct position

If any of those don't match, you'll need to decide whether the necessary changes are feasible and acceptable. That's mostly a matter of prerogative, so we can't say.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! You can STILL buy the P series extractor fan! I'm in the same situation and looking for a replacement motor, but for around £200 a new unit is available. - which is my plan B if I can't lube the motor bearings.

Comment: Well, just an update on my previous (in case someone else is looking for a solution to the Greenwood Airvac,  the motor is a Torin one, and is indestructible! It is a doddle to unscrew it and remove the rotor and relube it with some superlube. My unit dated 1984 is now running silently again.